# Creating a dynamic table in JS, "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript, html

I am supposed to create a table on a webpage dynamically, using JS.  I can not use .appendChild
I ran the JS script through JSLint and I got "Unused 'createTable'. function createTable() {" (besides it not liking my r++ and c++ expressions).  The Chrome debugger where I tested my code says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".  Any help in pointing where the error resides is greatly appreciated.

My simple code:

```js
function createTable() {
  var table = '';
  var r, c;
  var rowN = document.getElementById("rows").value;
  var colN = document.getElementById("columns").value;

  for (r = 1; r <= rowN; r++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    for (c = 1; c <= colN; c++) {
      table += '<td>' + c + '</td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
  }
  document.getElementByID('table').innerHTML = '<table border=1>' + table + '</table>';
}
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("onclick", createTable, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="nRows">
           Select number of rows: 
       </label>
    <select id="rows" name="rows" tabindex="1">
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <label for="nColumns">
           Select number of columns: 
       </label>
    <select id="columns" name="columns" tabindex="3">
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <input name="Submit1" tabindex="5" type="submit" value="Create Table" onclick="createTable()">
  <input name="Reset1" tabindex="7" type="reset" value="Clear values">    
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, you dont have an element with id "submit" , as far as I read your code none of your elements have Ids

Comment: You shouldn't use both `onclick="createTable()"` and `addEventListener`. It will call the function twice.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` returns null when it cannot find the element you are looking for.  I don't see an element with an id of submit.  You can change your html to this

Also removed the onClick property, since you are adding the event listener using js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form>
    <fieldset>
       <label for="nRows">
           Select number of rows: 
       </label>
           <select id="rows" name="rows" tabindex="1">
              <option value="01">01</option>
              <option value="02">02</option>
              <option value="03">03</option>
              <option value="04">04</option>
              <option value="05">05</option>
              <option value="06">06</option>
              <option value="07">07</option>
              <option value="08">08</option>
              <option value="09">09</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
       <label for="nColumns">
           Select number of columns: 
       </label>
           <select id="columns" name="columns" tabindex="3">
              <option value="01">01</option>
              <option value="02">02</option>
              <option value="03">03</option>
              <option value="04">04</option>
              <option value="05">05</option>
              <option value="06">06</option>
              <option value="07">07</option>
              <option value="08">08</option>
              <option value="09">09</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
           </select>
    </fieldset>
<input id="submit" name="Submit1" tabindex="5" type="submit" value="Create Table" >
<input name="Reset1" tabindex="7" type="reset" value="Clear values">
</html>
```

Secondly your for loop won't run because *`<s>rowN and colN variables are objects.  It seems like you want the amount of children within those elements so this should work. </s>`*

Wait sorry, your values come back as strings, you want to parse them into numbers.

```js
    function createTable() {
    var table = '';
    var r, c;
    var rowN = parseInt(document.getElementById("rows").value);
    var colN = parseInt(document.getElementById("columns").value);    

    for (r = 1; r <= rowN; r++)
    {
        table += '<tr>';
        for (c = 1; c <= colN; c++)
        {
            table += '<td>' + c + '</td>';
        }
        table += '</tr>';
    }    
    document.getElementByID('table').innerHTML = '<table border=1>' + table + '</table>';
}
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("onclick", createTable, false);
```

If you still get the same error make sure your load order is correct.  Move your script tags to the bottom of the body.

Comment: Oh that's why JSLint didn't like my r++ and c++, I was trying to increment on a string!  I have my JS script on the bottom of the HTML page, I forgot to include it here.  Thanks.